# Implementing search bar in Navigationbar using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented searchBar using UISearchController using following code -

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
// Fallback on earlier versions
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
navigationItem.titleView?.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Now I have two issues-

1. SearchBar comes below the navigationBar(See the image attached), how do I get the searchBar on top of NavigationBar that used to come when we implement searchBar with UISearch bar.
2. The cancel button is not coming on the right side of search bar.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this natively. But you can activate the search bar when you open the menu (dont forget to set `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `true`):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchController.isActive = true
}
```

But it will hide the `UINavigationBar` so this is not what you really want. So, maybe better, you can create a custom navigation bar and hide the native one. Here is a quick example:

1 - Create a swift a xib file NavigationBarView with an horizontal `UIStackView`, a back `UIButton` with a fixed width and a `UISearchBar`:

```
class NavigationBarView: UIView {

    var backAction: (()->Void)?
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBarView: UISearchBar!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Customize your search bar
        self.searchBarView.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.backAction?()
    }
}
```

2 - Instead of using a `UITableViewController`, create a `UIViewController` with a vertical `UIStackView` which contains a view with a fixed height of 64 and a `UITableView`:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    let navigationBarView: NavigationBarView = NavigationBarView.viewFromNib() // Custom helper to instantiate a view, see below

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true // hide the native UINavigationBar

        self.navigationBarView.backAction = {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        self.navigationBarView.searchBarView.delegate = self
        self.navigationBarView.add(in: self.containerView) // Custom helper to put a view in a container view, see below

        // Other stuff     
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
```

Here is my helpers:

```
extension UIView {
    static public func viewFromNib <GenericView: UIView> () -> GenericView {
        let className = String(describing: self)
        guard let instance = UINib(nibName: className, bundle: nil)
            .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? GenericView else {
                // If this happens, it means the xcodeproj is broken
                fatalError("Ho no its broken!")
        }
        return instance
    }

    func add(in superView: UIView) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superView.addSubview(self)
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try below code and please let me know if you are facing any issue.

```
if self.searchController != nil {
            self.searchController.isActive = false
        }
        isSearching =  true
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = false

        self.searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a property for this

   ```
   searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
   ```
2. There is a gap, so it might be a white text Canel button. ou can know it for sure in `Debugger Navigator` (Cmd+7) -> `View UI Hierarcy`. White button text might be caused by custom navigation bar style